# String formatting in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, formatting, format

Is there a printf()-like formatting in MySQL?
I couldn't find a straightforward way in the documentation.

For example, how can I make something like:

```
SELECT STRFORMATFUNCTIONIMLOOKINGFOR("%03d", 17)
```

to get 017 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement this kind of function by creating a new UDF (user defined function).E.g. see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-functions.html

Answer (score 5):

for your example, you could use

SELECT [LPAD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)(17, 3, '0');

there is also

SELECT [FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_format)(17, 3); -- 17.000

otherwise, UDF as mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it will be useful:

```
select lpad(1, 2, '0') str;
+-----+
| str |
+-----+
| 01  | 
+-----+
select lpad(11, 2, '0') str;
+-----+
| str |
+-----+
| 11  | 
+-----+
```

Answer (score 2):

see FORMAT() function:

```
mysql> SELECT FORMAT(12332.123456, 4);
returns '12,332.1235'
```

but it's only for formatting float numbers.

Answer (score 2):

```
-- 
-- Autor: Ivan Sansão.
-- 
-- Função para formatar strings.
-- Exemplo: select mask("0123456789","(##) ####-####");
-- Retorna: (01) 2345-6789

CREATE FUNCTION mask(texto VARCHAR(255), mascara VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS VARCHAR(255) CHARSET latin1
    Begin

        -- Contém o texto processado.
        DECLARE textoProcessado VARCHAR(255);
        SET textoProcessado = "";

        -- Se tem Texto.
        IF length(texto) > 0 THEN

            -- Percorre a máscara enquanto seu tamanho for maior que zero.
            WHILE Length(mascara) > 0 DO

                -- Se o caracter é um curinga.
                IF LEFT(mascara,1) = "#" THEN

                    -- Concatena o primeiro caracter do texto.
                    SET textoProcessado = concat(textoProcessado,LEFT(texto,1));

                    -- Elimina o primeiro caracter da máscara.
                    SET mascara = SUBSTRING(mascara,2,255);

                    -- Elimina o primeiro caracter do texto.
                    SET texto = SUBSTRING(texto,2,255);

                ELSE

                    -- Concatena o primeiro caracter da máscara.
                    SET textoProcessado = concat(textoProcessado,LEFT(mascara,1));

                    -- Elimina o primeiro caracter da máscara.
                    SET mascara = SUBSTRING(mascara,2,255);

                END IF;

            END WHILE;

        END IF;

    RETURN trim(textoProcessado);
END
```